# Is it possible to prepoulate the comments box while posting to facebook from an application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have added the facebook recommend/like button in my application. All I want is when user click on the recommend/like button then the comments box should be pre-poulated with some default text.

Is it possible to do this? if so how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about a facebook comments box: its not possible. Checkout this: [Facebook Like Button with prepopulated Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564550/facebook-like-button-with-prepopulated-comment)

Otherwise, if its a custom comment box, this will need to be done via javascript SDK. Check out the documentation for subscribing to like events on a page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).